# How to interpret the integrand in this surface integral?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let Ω be the region in $ℝ^3$ defined by
$$ Ω={(x_1,x_2,x_3):max(∣∣x_1∣∣,∣∣x_2∣∣,∣∣x_3∣∣)≤1}$$
Let ∂Ω denote the boundary of Ω.

Calculate
$$∫_{∂Ω}ϕF⋅ndσ$$

where n is the unit normal vector, dσ denotes integration over ∂Ω,

$F_i=\large \frac{x_i}{(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}^=\frac{x_i}{r^3}$

and $ϕ(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ is a continuously differentiable function of $\large y_i=\frac{x_i}{r}$. Assume that ϕ has unit mean over the unit sphere.

I just started on this problem so I don't want solutions.

**My question is:  how should I interpret $\phi F$?**  Is $\phi$ another vector field and that I should take the inner product of $\phi$ with $F$?

This wouldn't make much sense since; I'd end up with a scalar, and then scalar.$\vec n$ wouldn't really make sense either.

Any hints or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,

**EDIT:** I'd welcome solutions at this point.  I am getting weird computations -- such as an integral that is equal to zero.  I tried using the "product rule" that I found on Wolfram Alpha to compute the divergence of $\phi F$.  I notice first that divF=0, so F alone is divergence-free.  But I honestly do not know whether I have the correct vector field after multiplication with $\phi$.  So, when computing the divergence of $\phi F$, I might be using an incorrect vector field.

Comment: As you said, $\phi$ is actually a function, so $\phi F$ is a function times a vector fields, thus is still a vector field. Then $\phi F \cdot n$ is the inner product between these two vector fields.

Comment: Hi @JohnMa is $\phi$ a scalar-valued function?  Is $\phi F$ a composition of a scalar function with a vector field?  I'm a little confused with what this object is.  Can you elaborate just a bit more?  Thanks,

Comment: For example, if $F = (F_1, F_2, F_3)$ then $\phi F$ is another vector fields given by $(\phi F_1, \phi F_2, \phi F_3)$.

Comment: Hi @JohnMa, just one more question if you don't mind:  so you're saying it is sort of like a composition, in each component of F, but each component of F maps $R^3$ to $R$.  Then the input for $\phi$ is something in $R$.  But the way the problem statement gives $\phi$, it looks like $\phi$ should take *three* arguments, not just one.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: $\phi$ is a function with three variable, so $\phi(y_1, y_2, y_3)$ is a number. The sentence "Assume that $\phi$ has unit mean over the unit sphere" is a hint that my interpretation is correct (What does this mean if $\phi$ is a vector fields?)

Comment: Ah, yes - very good point.  Ok, I'll try this composition of functions now and proceed.  Thanks for your time, @JohnMa.

Comment: It's not **composition**, just multiplication.

Comment: Hi @mrf, ok, I will try again -- no wonder I did not arrive at the correct answer.  Thanks, professor.

Comment: Hi @mrf, this computation has been messier than I anticipated.  Is the correct vector field to integrate = $\phi F$ = $\large (\frac{(x_1)^2}{r^4}, \frac{(x_2)^2}{r^4}, \frac{(x_3)^2}{r^4})$?

Comment: I just multiplied $\large \frac{x_i}{r}$ with $\large \frac{x_i}{r^3}$.  What do you think @JohnMa?  Is my derivation of the vector field correct?  I sense that it may not be, since my computations are very messy and getting nowhere (I had tried to use the Divergence Theorem...), but perhaps my vector field is incorrect to begin with...

Comment: I just noticed a formula (on Wolfram Alpha) that is sort of like a "Product Rule" for computing the divergence of a (scalar function * vector function). I will try this now to see if this will be better, but feel free to comment further if you'd like, @mrf.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the expression is

$$\int_{\partial \Omega} \phi F \cdot \vec n d\sigma.$$

To use [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem), you better need to calculate

$$\text{div} (\phi F) = \nabla \phi \cdot F + \phi \text{div} F.$$

Now there are two terms on the right hand side. Note that the second term is zero as $\text{div} F = 0$. The first term is zero too, as $F = \frac{1}{r^3} (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and $\phi$ is constant along this direction.

Thus you actually have $\text{div}(\phi F) = 0$. Now because you know almost nothing about $\phi$, you only know that it's average on the unit sphere is $1$. Thus you want to change $\partial \Omega$ to the unit sphere. Now let $B$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb R^3$ centered at $0$. So $\partial B$ is the unit sphere. Note that $B \subset \Omega$. Let $M = \Omega\setminus B$. Then $\partial M = \partial \Omega - \partial B$. By the divergence theorem,

$$\int_{\partial M} \phi F \cdot \vec n d\sigma = \pm \int_M \text{div} (\phi F) dx = 0. $$

This imply 
$$\int_{\partial \Omega} \phi F \cdot \vec n d\sigma = \int_{\partial B} \phi F \cdot \vec n d\sigma$$

Now on the sphere $\partial B$, the normal vector is $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$, thus $F\cdot \vec n  =1$ and so

$$\int_{\partial B} \phi F \cdot \vec n d\sigma = \int_{\partial B} \phi d\sigma = \text{Area of the unit sphere} = 4\pi.$$

Comment: Hi @JohnMa - how do we know that phi is constant, when we don't even know its action explicitly?  I was guessing that you would possibly say something regarding orthogonality of phi against F - neither of which I am sure of.  But I would love to know why phi is constant.  Thanks,

Comment: Note that $\phi (x) = \phi (\frac{x_1}{r}, \frac{x_2}{r}, \frac{x_3}{r})$, so $\phi(tx) =  \phi (\frac{tx_1}{tr}, \frac{tx_2}{tr}, \frac{tx_3}{tr}) =  \phi (\frac{x_1}{r}, \frac{x_2}{r}, \frac{x_3}{r}) = \phi(x)$. Thus the value of $\phi$ is the same along each ray $\{tx : t>0\}$. @LebronJames

Comment: Hi @JohnMa - that is a  tricky and interesting geometric viewpoint, to evaluate phi along some fixed ray.  I agree with the algebra that you showed, but I have one last question, I think:  what you showed certainly means that phi does not change value per change in the length of the ray.  So, speaking in terms of spherical coordinates then, the partial derivative of phi, with respect to the radius = r, is zero.

Comment: But, how do we know that the other two partial derivatives of phi -- with respect to theta and gamma (let gamma be the angle between the point and the positive z-axis, since phi is already in use) ... are *also* zero, thus making $\nabla \phi$ = (0,0,0)?  Thanks,

Comment: No! @LebronJames it is not known if $\nabla \phi = 0$, I only know that along the $r$ direction, $\nabla_r \phi = 0$, but it is sufficient to show that $\nabla \phi \cdot F = 0$ as $F$ is parallel to the $r$-direction.

Comment: Hmm...so is the gradient, along the r direction = (0,0,0)?  The partial with respect to r is clearly zero, but the partial with respect to theta and gamma, along the r direction would be automatically zero?  There wouldn't be any change with the two angles theta and gamma along the ray.  Do I have it right now?  (I really hope so...) Thanks, @JohnMa

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding this object $∇ϕ⋅F=0$, geometrically, @JohnMa.  Is it an orthogonality argument, perhaps?  By definition, $\nabla \phi$ and the field F are orthogonal, if their inner product is zero.    Thanks,

Comment: $\nabla \phi$ is a vector, and it has no $F$ component as $\phi$ is constant along that direction. Basically we are using the formula $\nabla_V \phi = \nabla \phi \cdot V$ for all fixed vector $V$ ($\nabla_V \phi$ is the directional derivative of $\phi$ along $V$. @LebronJames

Comment: Ahhhh...that's so pretty.  Yes, of course.  That is an awesome argument.  Thanks a ton for your time and patience @JohnMa.  I learned a lot from you on this problem.  Have a great night :-)

Comment: Hi @JohnMa -- just out of curiousity does the directional derivative formula generalize to $R^4$ and higher dimensions (in Euclidean space)?  I Google searched for a bit just now and couldn't find this claim, although I would guess it is true and probably comes up first thing in introductory differential geometry.  Thanks,

Comment: In Euclidean space, if you have a function $\phi$ defined on an open set in $\mathbb R^n$, then as a vector $\nabla \phi$ is given by $\nabla \phi = (\partial_1 \phi, \partial_2 \phi, \cdots, \nabla_n \phi)$. It will also satisfies $\nabla \phi \cdot V = \partial_V \phi$. @LebronJames

Comment: Ok got it -- thanks again @JohnMa :-)